# utl_tcp.get_text waits for connection timeout if there are less characters in the buffer than requested

Tags: plsql, tcp, oracle19c

Somebody please help me before I beat myself to death with my keyboard.  I am trying to connect to a tcp service and get back a string.  Sounds straightforward, right?  Here is an MVP version of my code:

```
DECLARE
CONN         UTL_TCP.CONNECTION;
RETVAL       BINARY_INTEGER;
L_RESPONSE   VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
L_TEXT  VARCHAR2(1000);    

BEGIN

    --OPEN THE CONNECTION
    CONN := UTL_TCP.OPEN_CONNECTION(
        REMOTE_HOST   => 'MY.SERVER.IP.ADDRESS',
        REMOTE_PORT   => MYPORT,
        TX_TIMEOUT    => 20
        );

    L_TEXT := 'THE_TEXT_I_SEND';

    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN,L_TEXT);
    RETVAL := UTL_TCP.WRITE_LINE(CONN);

    BEGIN
        WHILE UTL_TCP.AVAILABLE(CONN,10) > 0 
            LOOP
                L_RESPONSE := L_RESPONSE ||  UTL_TCP.GET_TEXT(CONN,20);
            END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN UTL_TCP.END_OF_INPUT THEN
            NULL;
    END;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Response from Socket Server : ' || L_RESPONSE);
    UTL_TCP.CLOSE_CONNECTION(CONN);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,SQLERRM);
            UTL_TCP.CLOSE_CONNECTION(CONN);
    END;
```

This does work, I get back the correct result from the server.  However, I do not know the length of the response I am going to get back, so when I get to this line:

```
UTL_TCP.GET_TEXT(CONN,20)
```

if there are less than 20 characters in the buffer, it sits and waits for the timeout I have specified in the connection.  This is to be used in a production environment where someone is actively waiting on the result to do something, so it is hyper time critical.  It's compounded by the fact I have to send another command to the server based on the result of the first call.  I have spoken to the vendor of the software I am trying to interact with (they don't do PL/SQL, so can't help with the actual syntax), and they recommend a connection timeout of 30 seconds, so if I go with their recommendation I am going to have very unhappy customers waiting for over a minute for the response.  We are talking about lorry drivers and weighbridge operators here, not the most patient of people, especially when there is a queue of 10 lorries waiting to come across the weighbridge!

I have tried utl_tcp.get_line, instead of utl_tcp.get_text, but that just hangs for as long as the timeout and does not get a result at all.

I have tried fetching one character at a time from the buffer until it is empty and composing the result, but that takes longer than the timeout.

If I write the same thing in C#, I can read the number of characters in the buffer, so I can just fetch the exact number.  However, I have to use PL/SQL for this requirement as it is an Oracle Forms program that is making the call.

Any advice gratefully received.